# Finding the value of x within a given differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos^2(\frac{\pi y}{4})$.

I also know that $y=1$ when $x=0$. Which I believe can be written as the point $(0, 1)$ or $y(0) = 1$.

I am meant to find what $x$ equals when $y = 3$.

I figure I should integrate both sides to find $y$, and this leads me to $\int\frac{dy}{dx}=\int\cos^2(\frac{\pi y}{4}) = \frac{y}2 + \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi y}2)}\pi$.

I then substitute the given value $3$ for $y$ and get $\frac{3}2 + \frac{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})}\pi$.

Which simplifies to $\frac{3}2+\frac{-1}{\pi}$

My possible choices given for this particular problem are: $(\frac{1}8, -\frac{\pi}8, 1, -\frac{8}{\pi}, \frac{8}{\pi})$.

I don't believe this satisfies any of those given $x$ values for $y = 3$.

What is/are my mistake(s) in finding $x$; how could I fix them to solve for $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The equation is separable. So rewite is as $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\cos(\pi y/4)^2}$$ to get  $$x=\frac{4 \tan \left(\frac{\pi  y}{4}\right)}{\pi }+C$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I've found $x=-4\pi+C$. I'm trying to determine the value of the constant, but I find it to equal 1, which doesn't make much sense to me, considering $-\frac{4}{\pi}+1$ is not one of my given answers either.

Comment: If you use the equation as I wrote it, the condition $y(0)=1$ gives you $0=\frac {4}{\pi}+C$. Then, ...

Comment: Right, so, $C = \frac{-4}\pi$, meaning the solution for $x$ is $\frac{-8}{\pi}$, ja?

Comment: You got it for this range of values ! Cheers.

Comment: I hope you understand how wrong was your integration process. This is most important point. The remaining is simple ! Cheers again.